# Can't change move speed in Unity..my script has an error maybe?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-c++

I am a complete beginner, and I have a script to move a player in unity. However, the move speed is extremely fast and whenever I try to change in inspector or even in the script itself, it will always be super fast. I am wondering what I am doing wrong? This is my code

```
public float moveSpeed = 1;
public float leftRightSpeed = 4;
void Update()`
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed, Space.World);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x > LevelBoundary.leftSide) 
            
            {
              transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * leftRightSpeed);
            }

        }

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x < LevelBoundary.rightSide)
            {
              transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * leftRightSpeed * -1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`

Tried to change the speed in my script and through inspector, doesn't matter if I put the speed as 1, 0.0000001, or 5, it is always super fast.

Comment: Which move speed, you have two

Comment: You also move irrelevant of keys pressed then almost move as much again depending in what you pressed

Comment: Try use "FixedUpdate" instead of "Update", also you change the "Time.deltaTime" to "Time.fixedDeltaTime"

Comment: Moving an object inside the Update method will move with different speed based on the device your game is running, instead with FixedUpdate is gurantee that your object will move with the same speed on all devices

Comment: @PavlosMavris while this is not awful advice, its doesn't adress the cause of the problem. Multiplying by deltaTime already makes the operation framerate independent, using fixed update compicates the way input hast to be handled